# Definition of density operator/ Matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator

In Sakurai's book, the density operator is defined as
$$\rho\equiv \sum_i w_i|i\rangle \langle i|$$
where $w_i$ is statistical weight.

Now, I'm reading a book by Parisi, In which it says in Sec 5.1,

> We now introduce the density matrix or density operator of the system, denoted as $\rho$. This operator is a generalization of the projector $P_\psi$. Here we limit ourselves to the discrete case. Let us first discuss the case where the system admits a wave-function description i.e. $\rho=P_\psi$.

I don't how they defined
$$\rho\equiv|\psi\rangle \langle \psi|$$
What's the benefit of this? It's only the projector. It's also can make sense if $|\psi$ is an eigenstate of the system and we are considering pure ensemble so that $w_i$ is zero for other states. But here, they are (as it seems) of a general state which can be written in eigenbasis.
$$|\psi\rangle =\sum_i c_i|\phi_i\rangle \rightarrow \rho=\sum_{i,j}c_ic_j^*|\phi_j\rangle\langle \phi_i|$$
Can you explain what's the physical interpretation of the above?

---

Edit: I'm asking, what's the meaning or physical interpretation of the second definition? The first make sense in term of
$$\langle A\rangle =\text{Tr}(\rho A)$$
but not the second. It's simply the projection operator. How this become the density operator if system admits a wave-function description?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly your question is? *I don't how they defined [...]* is, IMO, not clear enough. Further: *Can you explain what does this mean?* - what are you referring to?

Comment: @Jakob I made few edits, Hope this is clear now.

Comment: Regarding the edit: Even with a pure state of the form $\rho = |\psi\rangle \langle \psi|$, it makes sense to define $\langle A\rangle_{\rho} = \mathrm{Tr} \rho A = \langle \psi|A|\psi\rangle$. Perhaps it would help if you search for a 'more general' definition of density operator. Both 'versions' you give are density operators (by definition).

Comment: @Jakob I'm what's so special about it. I can equivalently call $\rho$ to be the projection operator.

Comment: I have no idea what the question is - the "projector" is just the same as your initial definition with one $w_\psi = 1$ and the other $w_i = 0$. What, exactly, do you want to know? There is no claim here that the two cases are equivalent - the projector is a *special case*, as your quote explicitly says: *"Let us **first** discuss the case[...]"*

Comment: Yes. If $\rho$ is a pure state, it is (by definition) equal to a projection, in contrast to a convex combination of such. In general, pure density operators are the extreme elements in the convex set of density operators. Does this help?

Comment: @Jakob The writer wrote that "Let us first discuss the case where the system admits a wave-function description i.e. $P_\psi=\rho$. He hadn't mentioned pure state or anything before. I'm asking how this implication has been made.

Comment: @Jakob In the first definition the $|i\rangle $ form the basis for the space. But the second one doesn't say that $|\psi\rangle $ is an part of the eigenbasis. It's some general state.

Comment: @ACuriousMind It says, "Let us first discuss the case where the system admits a wave-function description". I don't understand how does this special case, makes $\rho =P_\psi$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The system admits a wave-function description" means there is just one single state (or "wavefunction") $\lvert \psi\rangle$ the system is in with absolute certainty. So in that case, the set of your $\lvert i\rangle$ is just the single state $\lvert \psi\rangle$ and it occurs with statistical weight $w_\psi = 1$. Obviously
$$ \rho = w_\psi\lvert \psi\rangle\langle \psi\rvert = \lvert \psi\rangle\langle\psi\rvert = P_\psi$$
in this case.

Comment: Why  is not measurement in 2 steps, lets take the singlet state : initial state : pure singlet state, intermediate state : mixed state with statistical weights given by qm born rule. End state : pure state chosen among the possible states ?

Comment: In fact they give the same average and probabilities, only powers of the density matrices were different